# How to get cookie from browser, dropped from another application

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, jsp, cookies

I have an application URL which generates xyz named cookie for me if the user is logged in, in browser. I want to hit the URL programatically(using Java/JSP) to look if the user is logged in or not.

Now every time when I hit the url from my Java code it doesn't find that cookie (xyz) as it creates new session on every request. This is probably because I am hitting the url from my code. Now how can I come up with this situation so that my application will create cookie in browser and my code will look for that cookie.

Comment: If reading and writing the cookie happens on the same domain, you should be able to see the cookie both in Javascript and your server side language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cookie is stored client-side by the browser of the user, so if you call the URL server-side it won't sent the cookie back with the response.

Comment: Thank you ! Even I thought this, but wasn't pretty sure.

Answer (score 0):

The way you are trying to know that user is logged in or not, can not be achieved through your approach.

Possible  workaround for our case is :

Implement the HttpSessionAttributeListener and override the method attributeAdded and attributeRemoved method of it.
When ever session is getting created for logged in user, you would be saving the userName attribute is session most probably. Once the userName attribute is getting saved, attributeAdded method of your listner will get called and you can see the name of user there, once user is logged out, attributeRemoved method will get called by trigger of session invalidate method and your listener will get the notification . You can see the name of user who has logged out.

See below example for detail explanation.
http://www.roseindia.net/servlets/SessionAttributeListenerExample.shtml